# Integer createparameter

Tags: vbscript, ado

I want to save a trainee to the database, so I created an insert query like this:

```
set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

cmd.ActiveConnection = objCon
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbOpleiders([opleiderDescr], [customerID]) VALUES(?, ?) "
Set paramdesc = cmd.CreateParameter("@descr", 200, 1, 100, newOpleidingsDescr)
Set paramcust = cmd.CreateParameter("@customer", 3, 1, 1000,customerID)
cmd.Parameters.Append paramdesc
cmd.Parameters.Append paramcust
```

Now I don't get the "CreateParameter" I found out that it this is : name,type,direction,size,value
the first parameter is logical, but why there should be a size with the 2nd parameter (the ID int field) ?

and the second questen why must the values be set as ?,? and not like in C# as: @descr, @customer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If you specify a variable-length data type in the *Type* argument, you must either pass a *Size* argument or set the Size property of the **Parameter** object before appending it to the **Parameters** collection; otherwise, an error occurs.

The 4<sup>th</sup> parameter is only required for variable length data types (e.g. `adVarChar`). For data types of fixed size (like `adInteger`) it can be omitted (if you provide a size anyway, that size is ignored):

```
Set paramcust = cmd.CreateParameter("@customer", 3, 1, , customerID)
```

As for using named parameters: they don't seem to work in ADO. I ran a quick test against my test DB, but even with [`NamedParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) set to `True` the parameters were passed in the order they were appended instead of matching them to the respective name in the query:

```
>>> Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
>>> cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
>>> cmd.NamedParameters = True
>>> cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Tab1] ([name], [val]) VALUES (@name, @val)"
>>> Set p1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@name", 200, 1, 20, "foobar")
>>> Set p2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@val", 3, 1, , 43)
>>> 'append parameters in correct order
>>> cmd.Parameters.Append p1
>>> cmd.Parameters.Append p2
>>> cmd.Execute
>>> 'no error here
>>> Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
>>> cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
>>> cmd.NamedParameters = True
>>> cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Tab1] ([name], [val]) VALUES (@name, @val)"
>>> Set p1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@name", 200, 1, 20, "foobar")
>>> Set p2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@val", 3, 1, , 43)
>>> 'append parameters in reversed order
>>> cmd.Parameters.Append p2
>>> cmd.Parameters.Append p1
>>> cmd.Execute
Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (0x80040E07)
```

I suspect that C# uses ADO.net rather than classic ADO, which seems to be different in this respect.